# What's the best method to implement `write()` method that support memoryview and bytes

Tags: python, pyserial, memoryview

**Background**

the `write()` method of file object with "wb" mode support both memoryview and bytes:

```
v = memoryview("abc")
with open("txt.txt", "wb") as f:
    f.write( v )
```

When I use the recommended method of pyserial that do `readline()`:

```
import serial
import io
ser = serial.serial_for_url('loop://', timeout=1)
sio = io.TextIOWrapper(io.BufferedRWPair(ser, ser))

sio.write(unicode("hello\n"))
sio.flush() # it is buffering. required to get the data out *now*
hello = sio.readline()
print hello == unicode("hello\n")
```

It raised error:`IOError: raw write() returned invalid length 22`.

I debuged this and found that the object passed to `ser.write()` from 
`io.BufferedRWPair` is a `memoryview` object. And in the `ser.write()`
code it use `bytes(data)` to convert the passed object, which get something
like "<memory at 0x061F54E0>".

**Question**

If I need to implement `write()` method, what's the best method that makes it
can handle both `memoryview` and `bytes` object?

Following is what I came up:

- use `isinstance()`
- `data = memoryview(data).tobytes()`

Comment: There's a big red warning in the docs: ["Warning: BufferedRWPair does not attempt to synchronize accesses to its underlying raw streams. You should not pass it the same object as reader and writer; use BufferedRandom instead."](http://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.BufferedRWPair) I don't know if this is related to your problem, but the way you're constructing `sio` is explicitly called out as a bad idea.